# WCF service works in Debug Mode but not in Release Mode

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, request, release

I create a web service called IdbServiceMonitorHost.
The service works in Debug mode but it rarely breakdowns in Release mode.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IIDBServiceMonitor
{
    [OperationContract]
    XMLStringResponse getXMLStrings(int serviceId, int requestId);

    [OperationContract]
    ServiceMonitorLogListResponse getServiceMonitorInfoList(int xmlLength);

    [OperationContract]
    ServiceGroupResponse getServiceGroups();

    [OperationContract]
    ServiceMonitorLogResponse getServiceLog(int serviceId, int requestId);

    [OperationContract]
    ServiceTypeResponse getServiceTypes();
}
```

When I call getServiceMonitorInfoList() method too many times in Release mode by using WCFTestClient, the service stops working and return xxxx.exe are stopped to working error message. However, In debug mode the service works well even if i send a request in every second. Here is the App.config file.

[AppConfig file](http://pastebin.com/zvnkp3xV)

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate with 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702741/wcf-service-runs-in-debug-mode-but-not-in-release

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work. Thanks